# istream crash in while-switch loop

Tags: c++, istream

I have a switch inside a while loop. After I call option 4 three times, the program crashes the next time I input the int which decides which case to go into in the switch. I have no idea why it happens.
This is the code of the while loop:

```
void Menu::start()
{
    Store st;
    int op=1,num,quantity;
    string name;
    while(op!=0)
    {
        cin>>op;
        try
        {
            switch(op)
            {
                    case 1:
            {
                cin>>num>>name;
                st.addProduct(num,name);
                break;
            }
            case 4:
                {
                    cin>>num>>quantity;
                    st.sellProduct(num,quantity);
                    break;
                }
            case 0:
                break;
            default:
                throw(exception("Unknown option, try again.\n"));
            } //end of switch
        } //end of try
//catches
    } //end of while
}

/*****************************************************************************
* function name: addProduct
* The Input: This Store, const& int num, const& string name
* The output: If product with given num doesn't exist in store, adds it to
* store.
* The Function operation: uses the products map.
*****************************************************************************/
void Store::addProduct( const int& num,const string& name )
{
    //if product doesn't exist in map, add it
    if(prods.find(num)==prods.end())
        prods.insert(pair<int,Product>(num,Product(num,name)));
    //otherwise issue an error
    else
        throw(AddProdException(num));
}

/*****************************************************************************
* function name: sellProduct
* The Input: This Store, const int& prodNum, const unsigned int& quantityBought
* The output: If product doesn't exist or quantityBought is more than 10 units
* more than quantity in stock, issues an error. Otherwise, sells the product
* and if needed, issues a shipment such that after the purchase the store will
* be left with 20 units.
* The Function operation: uses the products and orders map.
*****************************************************************************/
void Store::sellProduct( const int& prodNum, const unsigned int& quantityBought )
{
    if(prods.find(prodNum)!=prods.end())
    {
        Product& pr = prods.find(prodNum)->second;
        const int& signedQB=quantityBought, signedPQ=pr.getQuantity();
        if( signedPQ<signedQB-10 )
            //store can't supply product
            throw(BuyQuanException(prodNum,quantityBought));
        //make purchase
        else
        {
            //purchase only what left in stock
            if(signedPQ<signedQB )
            {
                //issue shipment
                Order order=Order(prodNum,20+quantityBought-pr.getQuantity());
                orders.insert(pair<int,Order>(order.getID(),order));
                //document order
                purchaseDocs.add(new Documentation(pr,quantityBought,
                    orders.find(order.getID())->second));
                //buy product
                pr.decreaseQuantity( pr.getQuantity() );
            }
            //purchase requested amount
            else
            {
                //buy product
                pr.decreaseQuantity( quantityBought );
                //document order
                purchaseDocs.add(new Documentation(pr,quantityBought));
            }
        } //else regarding making the purchase

    } //if regarding found the product
    //otherwise issue an error
    else
        throw(BuyProdException(prodNum));
}
```

After three enters to case 4, (and only to case 4, only after 3 times), it crashes next time it reaches cin>>op, inside the istream file. By crash, I mean the following error message pops up: "Unhandled exception at 0x4a34870c in Ex6.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation." Help would be welcomed!

Comment: just guessing, you're not using c++11, are you?; Anyways, you should [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) have a look at it.

Comment: What do you mean by “crash”? Furthermore, please reduce your code to a minimum before posting it here, and provide us with a minmal *compilable* code. Your posted code contains plenty of stuff that we don’t know, so we cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: updated question. And Jonas, not using c++11.

Comment: The only possible culprit if you're not throwing anything is `Store::sellProduct`. Why don't you post that?

Comment: updated question to contain sellProduct and addProduct. Error occurs after adding 1 product, selling some of the product 2 times and then choosing the next case to go into.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
const char* errStr=e.what();
cout<<errStr;
//errStr is a dynamically allocated string we don't need anymore <-----------
delete[] errStr;
```

Is a bad assumption. The `const char*` returned by `std::exception::what` is not dynamically allocated, it's just a pointer to a string allocated internally in the exception. You **must not** delete that pointer. You probably have some other errors in your code, but you should fix this.

Comment: I get your point, but it just that in MY exception (ProductException), errStr is dynamically allocated - so I must delete it to prevent memory leak... Don't I?

Comment: You should provide the definition of that exception. I assumed that your exception inherited `std::exception`(which looks logical since you called `ProductException::what()`).

Comment: @Idan: in such case make sure that your exception is copyable (and works correctly when copied).

Comment: ybungalobill is totally right. You should give us your ProductException definition, otherwise there's not much we can do.

Comment: mfontanini -it does inherit from exception but overrides what(). ybungalobill - I'm pretty sure you've found the problem - my exception is being copied shallowly and it causes problems. Thanks! p.s. The only reason I had a dynamically allocated pointer is because It didn't work with a non dynamically allocated pointer. I've updated my question to contain the Exception definition. Do you have any idea how I can implement what() without having to deal with the problems caused by the dynamic allocation?

Comment: Why don't you store and std::string inside the ProductException, and in the `what()` method, return `std::string::c_str()`? That way you won't handle any pointers, and your copy constructor/destructor can be the default ones.

Comment: Also, why does the error occur in the istream and not when re-deleting the pointer?

Comment: Double-deleting a pointer is undefined behavoiur. You don't know when it's going to produce an error(it might even not produce a visible error at all).

Comment: I did use std::string, and then converted it to char*. The easiest thing to do will be to just return string, but I can't do that, because exception's what() returns char*, and two methods cannot differ from one another by only return type.

Comment: std::string contains a method, `c_str()` which returns the `const char*` stored inside the std::string. You don't have to delete that, it's just a const pointer. So in your `what()` method, you could just `return your_error_string.c_str();`

Comment: It works, but I'm afraid it doesn't solve the problem - updated my questions to have the updated code, but it still crash in the same place it used to.

Comment: When I think about, it never cought an exception during the three enters to case 4, so it couldn't have been the exception's fault anyway!

Comment: You should give us a minimal(compilable) example to reproduce the error. By having a look at a 20 line snippet, it's really hard to deduce where the error comes from.

Comment: I'll try to minimalize the code to update in my question (the minimal compilable code is still very large). But, the thing with the c_str doesn't work, too. (It compiles, but I just realized its causing a run time error). Are you sure I can do that using the c_str()? I think the problem is, that I return a pointer to a local variable (a local const char), and when I leave the function, it is being deleted. So the pointer I'm returning points to a deleted variable, isn't it so?

Comment: You mean I should make the c style string a member of the exception?